# What pthread functions are used by boost interprocess?

Tags: pthreads, autoconf, boost-interprocess

I am using `boost::interprocess` to implement an IPC mechanism based on shared memory. I want this to be cross platform (including windows), and the build system is autotools. On some platforms boost::interprocess requires that you link with the library `librt` which implements some threading functions, but not on windows, or apple platforms (I think). See the following link:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/interprocess.html#interprocess.intro.introduction_building_interprocess

Now, in autotools I can do things conditionally depending on the host being windows, but it would be better to test if the required functions are available using [AC_SEARCH_LIBS](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Libraries.html). The AC_SEARCH_LIBS macro first checks if the functions are available with no libraries, then using a provided list of libraries in sequence.

To do the test, I need to know what functions to search for.

To be even more specific I need to use the following headers in my program:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
```

So what functions in `librt` are required by these headers, or what is the easiest way to find this out?